# Getting the current 'foreach' item inside a context of 'with' binding

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, data-binding

Suppose we have the following layout:

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: items">
    <tr>
        <td data-bind="with: $parent.inplaceEditorVm">
            <span data-bind="text: $parent.$data.OwnrPrefs"></span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

How can we access the properties of the current `foreach` item in the context of the `with` binding?

I.E. In the example above, what do we need to write in a `data-bind` expression for the `span` element to get the value of the `OwnrPrefs` of the current `foreach` item?

When I'm using `$parent.$data.OwnrPrefs` like in the above example, it throws:

> TypeError: Unable to get property 'OwnrPrefs' of undefined or null
>   reference

And when I'm trying to use `$data.OwnrPrefs`, the value of this expression is resolved to `undefined`, since the `$data` inside the scope of the `with` binding is the `inplaceEditorVm` object, not the current `foreach` item.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bindings such as `with` and `foreach` create new [binding contexts](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-context.html).  The outer/original context, ie the one outside the `with`, is available as `$parent` - this is what `$parent` refers to, it's not (directly) related to your viewmodel structure, but rather the bindings on the page.

In your case, you can do:

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: items">
    <tr>
        <td data-bind="with: $parent.inplaceEditorVm">
            <span data-bind="text: $parent.OwnrPrefs"></span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```